# Read table metadata from multiple Microsoft Access databases

Tags: microsoft-access

I have 30+ Access databases in a directory. I think that some of them are forks of other databases in the same directory. A way to detect them is to check creation times of tables, but this way I need to open files and tables one by one and write down creation time.

Is there an easy way to automate this? Is there a way to read creation time of the tables of a batch of Access files?

Comment: Since I got no answer here, I asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65248898/read-table-metadata-from-a-batch-of-ms-access-databases/65249471#65249471 some days later